# Make an arithmetic logic unit in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, quartus, alu

I need to make an arithmetic logic unit in VHDL for the pic16f684.
So the instructions for the ALU can be found in the datasheet of the pic16f684.

The instructions I need to make are the following:

[These are the instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzWk1.png)

This is my code so far, but I get, which is quite logic, the error that a std_logic_vector can't have a character in the vector, but I don't know how to do it in a other way..

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

ENTITY AluPIC IS

   PORT(    -- Input Signals    
        Op_code     : in std_logic_vector(6 DOWNTO 0);
        win, fin        : in std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
         -- Output Signals
        d,z : out std_logic;
        ALU_output  : out std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0));


END AluPIC;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF AluPIC IS
        -- declare signal(s) internal to module here
SIGNAL temp_output,wout,fout: std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN
  PROCESS (Op_code, win, fin)
    BEGIN
        -- Select Arithmetic/Logical Operation
    CASE Op_Code (6 DOWNTO 0) IS
        WHEN "000111d" =>
            if d ='0' then
                wout <= win + fin;
                temp_output <=wout;
            else
                fout <= win + fin;
                temp_output <= fout;
            end if;

        WHEN "000101d" =>
            if d ='0' then
                wout <= win and fin;
                temp_output <= wout;
            else
                fout <= win and fin;
                temp_output <= fout;
            end if;

        WHEN "000001l" =>
             fout <= fin;
             fout <= "00000000";
             z <= '1';
             temp_output <= fout;

        WHEN "001010d" =>
            fout <= fin+1;
             if d = '0' then
                wout <= fout;
                temp_output <=wout;
             else
                fout <= fout;
                temp_output <=fout;
            end if;

        WHEN "001000d" =>
        if d = '0' then
            wout  <= fin;
            temp_output <= wout;
            z <= '1';
        else
            fout <= fin;
            temp_output <= fout;
            z <= '1';
        end if;

        WHEN "0101bbb" =>
            fout <= fin;
             temp_output <= fout;
        WHEN OTHERS =>
            temp_output <= "00000000";
    END CASE;
            -- Select Shift Operation
    IF Op_Code(0) = '1' THEN
            -- Shift bits left with zero fill using concatination operator
            -- can also use VHDL 1076-1993 shift operator such as SLL 
        Alu_output <= temp_output(6 DOWNTO 0) & '0';
    ELSE 
        Alu_output <= temp_output;
    END IF;
  END PROCESS;
END behavior;
```

Thanks for your time guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines like `WHEN "000111d" =>` or `WHEN "0101bbb" =>` are not valid, because your `case` statement uses an `std_logic_vector`, but `"000111d"` is a string.

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve with your `d` and `b` characters, but your various `when` lines should compare against a valid `std_logic_vector` of the correct length, for example `WHEN "0000111" =>`.

Looking at your op code image, it shows a table with lines containing operations, for example 'ADDWF'. In these operations, only the most significant 6 bits seem to select the operation, with the least significant bit being labelled `b` or `d`. This least significant bit is actually a parameter for the operation, not part of the opcode. The table does not show what effect `d` has on the operation, but you seem to have worked this out. Using `ADDWF` as an example, I would change your code like this:

```
CASE Op_Code (6 DOWNTO 1) IS
  WHEN "000111" =>
    if Op_Code(0) ='0' then
      wout <= win + fin;
      temp_output <=wout;
    else
      fout <= win + fin;
      temp_output <= fout;
    end if;
  -- ...
end case;
```

The 'BSF' operation is the exception, as it uses the least significant 3 bits as a parameter. You can write this either using a matching case statement, or by listing all the possibilities in one case:

Matching case, requiring VHDL2008:

```
CASE? Op_Code (6 DOWNTO 1) IS
  WHEN "0101--" =>
    -- Set a bit based on `op_code (2 downto 0)`
end case?;
```

List all possibilities:

```
CASE Op_Code (6 DOWNTO 1) IS
  WHEN "010100" | "010101" | "010110" | "010111" =>
    -- Set a bit based on `op_code (2 downto 0)`
end case;
```

Comment: Ye so far that was clear, but how can I solve this in a other way? Because if you look at the instructions, 01bb is used and how can I put this instructions in the std_logic_vector?

Comment: You have to read the PIC manuals in more depth to understand what they mean by `bb` or `d` and make the appropriate changes.

Comment: ok @Faalhaaz I think I understood the question, please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks so much!, It didn't only give me the solution but now I do understand it a lot better!

Comment: Btw @scary_jeff, the ? after the case statement, what does that mean?

Comment: @Faalhaaz https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_small/#matchcase